# filtering for n char inside a value in r

Tags: r, dplyr, analysis, sentiment-analysis

i'm doing sentiment analysis, but I need to filter by n char inside every tweet. I mean:

```
df <- c("the most beauty", "the most ugly", "you are beauty")
Library(dplyr)
df %>%
filter((n char >3) %in% df)
```

Im expecting a result like: "most beauty", "ugly", "beauty"

I've tried with `$str_detect` but is useless

Comment: `df` is a `vector` as showed in the example..  Also did you meant `nchar(columnname)`  Based on the result may be `sapply(strsplit(df, " "), function(x) paste(x[nchar(x) > 3], collapse= " "))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with a regex to match words that have characters from 1 to 3 and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("\\s*\\b[^ ]{1,3}\\b\\s*", "", df)
#[1] "most beauty" "most ugly"   "beauty"
```

NOTE: 'df' is a `vector` and not a `data.frame/tbl_df`.  So the `tidyverse` methods with `filter` won't work

Answer (score 0):

For sentiment analysis filtering by a predetermined `nchar()` might be a bit crude. I'd recommend looking [the `tidytext` library](https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html), which will allow you to tokenize meaningful units of text like words into a tidy data structure.

In your case, you can convert each word into a token and reshape the dataframe so that each token (or word) is on a separate row. Then you can easily filter out articles and other irrelevant stuff. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

df <- c("the most beauty", "the most ugly", "you are beauty")
text_df <- data_frame(line = 1:3, text = df)
text_df %>%
   unnest_tokens(word, text)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
   line word  
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 the   
2     1 most  
3     1 beauty
4     2 the   
5     2 most  
6     2 ugly  
7     3 you   
8     3 are   
9     3 beauty
```

Then, simply filter out any with a vector of unwanted words.

```
remove_words <- c("the", "a", "you", "are")
text_df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% filter(!(word %in% remove_words))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
   line word  
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 most  
2     1 beauty
3     2 most  
4     2 ugly  
5     3 beauty
```

Tokenization allows you to easily compute sentiment scores for each tweet by summing sentiment scores for all words in the tweet. Examples can be found here: https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html